# WCF service application does not load on IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, wcf-binding, wcf-security

So, i am trying to host a WCF application and to simplify the problem, i have now created a simple template 'WCF Service Application' on Visual studio 2013 and trying to host it on IIS by adding it to default site through add application and have given permission to IIS_IUSRS but the url seems to load and load, nothing shows up at all.i have also done aspnet_regiis -i but no luck.

Comment: Did you tried to load the svc file in IIS Manager ?

Comment: What version of .NET?  3.5 or 4.0?  If 3.5, you need to make sure you've enabled the 3.5 components and WAS.  Also, you can try the [ServiceModel Registration Tool (ServiceModelReg.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)